# What does New and Dispose do internally?

Tags: delphi

I was wondering about what happens internally when New and Disposed is called. Delphi help gives a reasonable explanation but what would have to be done if a person would write one's own New and Dispose? Which methods are called internally to the two or is it all assembly?

I am not looking to write my own New and Dispose. I am just extremely curious about both methods' internal working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`New` does the following:

1. Allocate memory for the new object with a call to `GetMem`.
2. Initialize any managed fields such as strings, interfaces, dynamic arrays etc.

`Dispose` reverses this:

1. Finalize the managed fields.
2. Deallocate the memory with a call to `FreeMem`.

Note that both `New` and `Dispose` are [intrinsic functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines). This means that the compiler has extra knowledge of them and is able to vary how they are implemented depending on the type in question.

For instance, if the type has no managed fields then `New` is optimized into a simple call to `GetMem`. If the type has managed fields then `New` is implemented with a call to `System._New`, which performs the steps described above.

The implementation of `Dispose` is much the same. A simple call to `FreeMem` for non-managed types, and a call to `System._Dispose` otherwise.

Now, `System._New` is implemented like this:

```
function _New(Size: NativeInt; TypeInfo: Pointer): Pointer;
begin
  GetMem(Result, Size);
  if Result <> nil then
    _Initialize(Result, TypeInfo);
end;
```

Note that I have just shown the `PUREPASCAL` variant for simplicity. The call to `GetMem` is simple enough. The call to `System._Initialize` is a lot more involved. That uses the `TypeInfo` argument to find all the managed types contained in the object and initialize them. This is a recursive process because, for example, a record may contain members that are themselves structure types. You can see all the gory details in the RTL source.

As for `System._Dispose`, it calls `System._Finalize` and then `FreeMem`. And `System._Finalize` is very similar to `System._Initialize` except that it finalizes managed types rather than initializing them.

It's long been something of a bug bear of performance sensitive Delphi users that `System._Initialize` and `System._Finalize` are implemented this way, on top of runtime type information. The types are known at compile time and the compiler could be written to inline the initialization and finalization which would result in better performance.

Comment: Thanks David. Would one be able to write a faster implementaion specific to a certain record type?

Comment: For managed type a call to `GetMem` followed by zeroising the memory would often be faster. For unmanaged types, there's nothing to be gained.

Comment: I think I understand now.

Comment: May I assume that intrinsic functions like SetLength() and Length() will also be handled much in the same way by the compiler and that they will point to procedures like _SetLength(), _LStrSetLength(), _UStrSetLength() when SetLength() is used and _DynArrayLength() function for when Length() is used all depending on the original arguments and that I can study those methods' code if I needed to find out what SetLength() and Length() actually does?

Comment: Debugging the code will lead you to the relevant support methods

Answer (score 4):

It is how to write your own `New()` and `Dispose()` functions, with your own record initialization/finalization:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

procedure RecordInitialize(Dest, TypeInfo: pointer);
asm
  {$ifdef CPUX64}
  .NOFRAME
  {$endif}
  jmp System.@InitializeRecord
end;

procedure RecordClear(Dest, TypeInfo: pointer);
asm
  {$ifdef CPUX64}
  .NOFRAME
  {$endif}
  jmp System.@FinalizeRecord
end;

function NewRec1(TypeInfo: pointer): pointer;
begin
  GetMem(result, GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.RecSize);
  RecordInitialize(result, TypeInfo);
end;

function NewRec2(TypeInfo: pointer): pointer;
var
  len: integer;
begin
  len := GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.RecSize;
  GetMem(result, len);
  FillChar(result^, len, 0);
end;

procedure NewDispose(Rec: pointer; TypeInfo: Pointer);
begin
  RecordClear(Rec, TypeInfo);
  FreeMem(Rec);
end;
```

First, there is a low-level asm trick to call the hidden intrinsic functions we need.

I then propose two ways of initializing the record, one using `System.@InitializeRecord`, the other using `FillChar`. Also note that if you allocate your records within a dynamic array, the initialization/finalization of the items would be done automatically. And initialization won't call `Initialize()` but `FillChar` to fill the memory with zeros.

It is a pity that we could not define global functions/procedures with generic parameters, otherwise we may have get rid of the `TypeInfo()` parameter.

Some years ago, I re-wrote the [RTL part of record initialization/finalization](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/01/18/Enhanced-System-Run-Time-for-Delphi-7-and-Delphi-2007), for faster execution. Note that `TObject` would call `FinalizeRecord`, so it is a part of the RTL which gain of being optimized. The compiler should emit the code instead of using the RTTI - but at least the RTL should be optimized a bit more.

If you use our [Open Source `SynCommons.pas`](http://synopse.info/files/html/api-1.18/SynCommons.html) unit, and define the `DOPATCHTRTL` conditional for your project, you will have in-process patch of the RTL `FillChar Move RecordCopy FinalizeRecord InitializeRecord TObject.CleanupInstance` low-level functions, which would use optimized asssembly, and SSE2 opcodes if available.